# How to use Django workers efficiently?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am new to Django and first time using celery for distributed task. In below given snippet, I want to call **get** over each tuple in table TaskId. But my code is so basic and it is not at all using celery at its best. 
Please suggest me how to run different workers on different tuples in table without any duplicate task.

```
@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')),
    name="retrieve_mails_per_user",
    ignore_result=True
)
def retrieve_mails_per_user():
    """
    scheduled retrieval of mails
    """
    for count in TaskId.objects.all():
        user_id = count.request_id
        label_id = count.label
        task_id = TaskId.objects.filter(request_id=user_id, label=label_id)
        if task_id:
            TaskId.objects.filter(request_id = user_id, label = label_id).delete()
            get(user_id, label_id)
            logger.info("Saved one request mails!")



    logger.info("Saved mails!")
```

Comment: Did you run the celery workers?

Comment: yeah i did...but then the worker started running same task which was being executed by another worker. thats why I used             { TaskId.objects.filter(request_id = user_id, label = label_id).delete() }